# PHPStan throws undefined static method when using custom rules in Respect/Validation

Tags: php, validation, analysis, respect-validation, phpstan

I'm using [Respect/Validation](https://github.com/Respect/Validation) class and I have custom rule `CustomRule()` which works fine:

```
use Respect\Validation\Validator as v;

// ...

'email' => v::CustomRule()->email()->setName('email');
```

But this causes PHPStan to throw an error:

`Call to an undefined static method Respect\Validation\Validator::CustomRule().`

But if I move it after a built-in rule (e.g., `email()`), PHPStan works fine, no errors:

`'email' => v::email()->CustomRule()->setName('email');`

To be clear, both code works but PHPStan thinks the first code is invalid.

Any workaround so that PHPStan will accept it even if `CustomRule()` was set first?

**Update:**

I've found that if I edit the doc block of `Respect\Validation\Validator` class and append my custom rule to the list of its built-in rules, it works!

```
/**
* ...
* @method static Validator CustomRule()
*/
class Validator extends AllOf
...
```

Of course it's a bad idea to directly modify the doc block from the main class. That said, my question still remains the same. Or, maybe is there a way for PHPStan to honor my own doc block from my `CustomRule` class?

Comment: I have the same issue on where the file name and class name doesn't match. `phpstan` will prompt errors complaining it can't find the class of the static function.

Comment: If you were my case, another possible solution is to use `autoload_files` parameter in the `phpstan.neon`. Reference: https://github.com/phpstan/phpstan/issues/2533

Answer (score 3):

Ran into the same issue. What I did was just to add the custom Validators to phpstan config file (phpstan.neon). 
It can be done with regex eg:

```
parameters:
    ignoreErrors:
        - '#Call to an undefined method Respect\\Validation\\Validator::[a-zA-Z0-9\\_]()#'
```

Docs: https://github.com/phpstan/phpstan#ignore-error-messages-with-regular-expressions

More of a workaround I guess though.

Comment: This is just hidding the error but not fixing the issue. Personally I don't like this answer unless there is no choice of fixing. I would like to know the root cause of this phenomenon.

Comment: @JasonLiu - there is no issue, it's a false positive. You can tell PHPStan in one of the two ways about it: telling it to hide the error, or write a custom rule that will dynamically provide information about this particular method. The second way is "more correct" in a way, but it's a waste of your time.